# Expected number of trips until the professor gets wet

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Many people have asked this umbrella question, but I can't seem to find an answer to my particular question. It is based on question 5 on [this pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/150/takis_exercises.pdf).

> I start with 4 umbrellas at home. I keep moving
> between home and office. I take an umbrella with me only if it rains.
> If it does not rain I leave the umbrella behind (at home or in the
> office). It may happen that all umbrellas are in one place, I am at
> the other, it starts raining and must leave, so I get wet.

Suppose the probability of rain is $p$. What is the expected number of trips until I get wet?

First, I follow the Markov approach and create states $S_i$, where $S_i$ means that I'm in a place with $i$ umbrellas. Then $i$ goes from $0$ to $4$. The Markov matrix is given by

$$ P  = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1-p & p \\
0 & 0 & 1-p & p & 0 \\
0 & 1-p & p & 0 & 0 \\
1-p & p & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$

I then use this matrix to compute the expected number of trips to go from $S_4$ to $S_0$. I can work out the algebra, but it takes a very long time. I wonder if there's a shortcut?

Even then, I can't answer the question on the expected number of trips to get wet. Can I get a hint?

Furthermore, is there a way to generalize this to $N$ umbrellas?

Comment: There is a solution at
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-445-introduction-to-stochastic-processes-spring-2015/bc936647029c547c8be2bcc47f7394de_MIT18_445S15_homework3_sol.pdf

Comment: My question is simpler. If you can adapt their answer to my question, I'll select it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have $N>0$ umbrellas, $0<p<1$ and for each nonnegative integer $i\le N$ let $E_i$ be the expected number of trips until you get wet when there are $i$ umbrellas at the place where you are.
Then $$E_0=p+(1-p)(E_N+1)$$ and $$E_i=1+p E_{N-i+1}+(1-p) E_{N-i}$$ for each natural $i\le N$. This is a system of $N+1$ linear equations for $N+1$ variables, and I hope it has a unique solution. Maybe there is a general expression for it, but for $N=4$ the system should be  easily solvable. Anyway, when we sum all equations and cancel the same terms, we obtain $pE_0=N+1$, so $E_0=\frac{N+1}{p}$, and thus $E_N=\frac{N+1-p}{p(1-p)}$.

Comment: Did you make a typo somewhere? According to this [doc](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-445-introduction-to-stochastic-processes-spring-2015/bc936647029c547c8be2bcc47f7394de_MIT18_445S15_homework3_sol.pdf), the numerator should be $N + 1 - p$.

Comment: @user1691278 Thanks. I am sorry for the error. I found and fixed it.  By the way, their initial conditions are different. They have $k\in (0,1)$ whereas you have $k=0$.